# CPLEX Python API: Why does CPLEX 12.8 take more time to solve than CPLEX 12.5 at (mostly) default parameter settings?

Tags: python, cplex

I am working on a performance comparison of CPLEX 12.5 v/s CPLEX 12.8. I am using CPLEX Python (v2.7.15) API to read `.sav` files. I first did a trial run for about 32 `.sav` files, for which the following is the summary of total solve times (in seconds):

```
CPLEX 12.5: mean = 252.4; median = 127.0; standard deviation = 360.0
CPLEX 12.8: mean = 256.7; median = 129.5; standard deviation = 351.8
```

There were only 4 out of 32 `.sav` files in which CPLEX 12.8 took less time than CPLEX 12.5. CPLEX 12.8 took 4.2 seconds less on an average for these 4 files, and took 5.5 seconds more on an average for the remaining 28 files. As you can see in the code below, I am only changing four parameter settings: `timelim_cb.timelimit = 3600` to stop run time at 1 hour, `c.parameters.workmem.set(64)` to set the work memory to 64 MB, `c.parameters.mip.strategy.file.set(3)` to compress and store node files to disk, and `c.parameters.workdir.set(r'C:\Users\username\folder')` to change the working directory.

I expected CPLEX 12.8 to take less time to solve, but that didn't happen. It would be very helpful if someone can point me to what additional parameters/settings/ideas I should explore so as to find out an explanation for the results I got. I know that the default `workmem` parameter setting is 128 MB for CPLEX 12.5 and 2048 MB for CPLEX 12.8. I set this to 64 MB for both, because previously for CPLEX 12.5, I had been getting an error: `Warning: MIP starts not constructed because of out-of-memory status. Consider decreasing WorkMem parameter value to reduce memory usage. CPLEX Error  1001: Out of memory.`

My laptop's features are: Windows 10, Intel Core i7-6600U @2.60GHz, 8 GB RAM, 64 bit.

Code:

```
    import cplex
    import sys
    from cplex.callbacks import MIPInfoCallback

    class TimeLimitCallback(MIPInfoCallback):

        def __call__(self):
            if not self.aborted and self.has_incumbent():
                gap = 100.0 * self.get_MIP_relative_gap()
                timeused = self.get_time() - self.starttime
                if timeused > self.timelimit:
                    print("Good enough solution at", timeused, "sec., gap =",
                          gap, "%, quitting.")
                    self.aborted = True
                    self.abort()

    def solveCplex(filename):
        c = cplex.Cplex(filename)
        timelim_cb = c.register_callback(TimeLimitCallback)
        timelim_cb.starttime = c.get_time()
        timelim_cb.timelimit = 3600
        timelim_cb.aborted = False

        c.parameters.workmem.set(64)
        c.parameters.mip.strategy.file.set(3)
        c.parameters.workdir.set(r'C:\Users\username\folder')
        start_time = timelim_cb.starttime
        c.solve()
        end_time = c.get_time()
        print '\n'+'printing solutions'+'\n'

        obj_val = c.solution.get_objective_value()
        best_obj_val = c.solution.MIP.get_best_objective()
        abs_gap = best_obj_val - obj_val
        rel_gap = 100 * c.solution.MIP.get_mip_relative_gap()
        sol_time = end_time - start_time
        return [obj_val, abs_gap, rel_gap, sol_time]

    solveCplex('filename.sav')
```

Comment: Let's start simple: what makes you think, CPLEX 12.8 should beat CPLEX 12.5 for *your* instances? Are you aware with all the keywords like *NP-hardness*, *no-free-lunch-theorem* and *heuristics*? Yes, it is to be expected that a newer version improves results *over* the benchmark set the developers are using (which is also probably one of their trade secrets). But that does not mean, that one of their benchmark-parts or even worse: your instances won't get slower on average. And as i'm a bit rusty / lazy on the statistics side: did you do any statistical-significance check on your results?

Comment: @sascha Thank you for your comment. Like you said, I thought that a newer version would be quicker to solve. And yes, I did some statistical tests (for all 32 files) and inferred based on p-values that the results (differences between CPLEX 12.5 and 12.8 solve times) are not statistically significant! For the 4 files I mentioned above, I should have mentioned that the solve times are about 600 or 700 seconds. But I got your point, thank you!